# Why is my query giving the error of "bad double value"?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm trying to sum the total talk-time (five9__five9handletime__c) a phone rep has and count the number of tasks associated with a contact.

Whenever I try to run my query without a CAST, it gives me an error because it's a STRING. However, when I CAST it to a FLOAT64, it gives me an error for 'bad double value'. Then, when I SAFE_CAST to an INT64 or FLOAT64 it returns the values as NULL.

```
SELECT
  ap.id AS action_plan,
  SUM(SAFE_CAST(t.five9__five9handletime__c AS INT64)),
  COUNT(t.id) AS calls_made
FROM
  tack_v2.contact c
INNER JOIN tack_v2.action_plan ap ON ap.contact__c = c.id
INNER JOIN reference.tsl_ops_roster r ON ap.ownerid = r.salesforce_id_18
  AND SAFE_CAST(r.team_end_date AS DATE) = '2999-12-31'
INNER JOIN tack_v2.task t ON t.whoid = c.id
WHERE t.activitydate BETWEEN '2019-06-01' AND '2019-09-30'
  AND t.five9__five9handletime__c IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY ap.id
```

Expected the result to show the SUM of **five9__five9handletime__c** and the COUNT of **t.id** associated with each **contact.id**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously, you have bad values in the data.  You can find them using:

```
select t.five9__five9handletime__c
from tack_v2.task t
where safe_cast(t.five9__five9handletime__c as int64) is null and
      t.five9__five9handletime__c is not null;
```

Then you'll need to fix your data/logic.

Moral:  do not store numeric values as strings.